# How to compare two strings, one of which with backquotes

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am writing tests for my components and trying to compare two lines. However, the line in my code is enclosed in reverse quotes, and as a result, the test compares the line with spaces and the line without spaces, which end up not being equal. If I use concatenation, then everything works. How can I compare two lines in my test? I have an idea to remove spaces with a regular expression, but this idea does not seem successful to me

```
      code 
      ...
    func test () => {
    return `${ a }
            ${ b } 
            ${ c }`
    }

      test
    ...
    resultingString = 'abc'

    expect(component.test()).toEqual(resultingString);
```

but if I use

```
 code
...
return a + b + c
```

It's work in test.

Comment: The template literal has newline characters. So this will return 'abc': ``return `${ a }${ b }${ c }` ``

Comment: These lines are too long and do not fit in one line in my code.

Comment: Well, if you *expect* the result to have newlines, then set your expected string to also have newlines. If you expect the result to *not* have them, then your test is correct and the implementation is wrong. Not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Problem is new lines.... `console.log(escape(component.test())` The line breaks are part of the string, hence why it does not match.

Comment: You can add the linebreaks just *after* the opening brace.

Comment: _"These lines are too long and do not fit in one line in my code."_ Ok, then assign whatever's in them to variables a, b, and c, and then return `a + b + c`. Problem solved. There's no rule that says the entire contents of your function have to be in a single template literal, is there?

Comment: it's a big project and we have linter

Comment: @MichaelGeorge Does the linter say that you're not allowed to create variables?? What lint rule are you trying to please here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're inventing problems that don't need to exist. As explained in the comments, your returned string contains extraneous spaces and newlines, which is why it doesn't match. So, good news! The test is doing its job and identifying a problem in your implementation.

Just do this:

```
func test () => {
    const a = (expression for a);
    const b = (expression for b);
    const c = (expression for c);

    return a + b + c;
}
```